# Running php script from book using command line

Tags: php, linux, command-line, debian

I am trying to run this php script that i got from the book webbots, spiders, and screen scrappers.

```
  $target = "http://www.WebbotsSpidersScreenScrapers.com/hello_world.html";
$file_handle = fopen($target, "r");

# Fetch the file
while(!feof($file_handle))
  echo fgets($file_handle, 4096);
fclose($file_handle);
```

I am using the command php first.php and all it does is concatenate the file back to me.

Comment: So don't you see the output? Could you elaborate on the problem you're having?

Comment: All i see is the actual script it self.  As if i am typing cat first.php

Comment: Just to confirm, but you have `<?php` at the top right?

Comment: At the top of your script, add the `<?php` marker.

Answer (score 1):

Your full script should look like this

```
<?php  //<- opening tag for PHP

$target = "http://www.WebbotsSpidersScreenScrapers.com/hello_world.html";
$file_handle = fopen($target, "r");

# Fetch the file
while(!feof($file_handle)) {
  echo fgets($file_handle, 4096);
}
fclose($file_handle);
```

Comment: Sidenote: this example is correct because many don't know that the closing `?>` tag is not necessary if at the end of the script.